# Friend class read only access C++

Tags: c++, friend-class

My question is somewhat similar to the title of [friend class with limited access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609472/friend-class-with-limited-access). But the limited access I define by 'access-only'. I mean, I've a main class which does the work and creating a helper class which is useful for displaying the internals for debugging purposes. So, inside Main I defined Helper as friend.

Now I want the Helper class to just have read only access to private variables and not write access. Is it possible?

```
class Main {
 private:
  // DSs that I don't want to expose it to rest
  // even through getters and setters.
  DataStrcuture ds_;

  // I want a way to specify that no modifications should be
  // allowed through this helper.
  friend class Helper;
}
```

Now I have my helper class.

```
class Helper {
  Helper(Main *main) : main_(main) {
  }

  void ShowStatsAndDebugInfo() const {
    PrettyPrint(main_->ds_);
  }

 private:
  // I want this to always be used like a const variable.
  Main *main_;
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424042/class-variables-public-access-read-only-but-private-access-read-write), it's a similar problem

Comment: Yes. Pass your class Main object to the Helper by const pointer or reference.

Comment: Limiting access is rarely hard. Show us the code to get proper helpful examples.

Comment: Without seeing more code I'm inclined to saying that you need separation of concerns.

Comment: @TedLyngmo didn't get you

Comment: You are mixing concerns (probably). Who does what? Get that in order and it'll usually be easy to fix the rest.

Comment: Why friend to `Helper` if you want read-only access in the first place ? Just to get to the private members ? If so why not declare `main_` in `Helper` as `Main const *` ? (friended or not, makes no difference; friending isn't a magic key to unlock an otherwise-const restriction).